# How to implement billboarding?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I currently draw a plane (triangle strip) in the 3D world. I now want to draw it as a billboard - so the face is aligned to the camera.

This is the code:

```
#version 330 core

layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices=4) out;
out vec2 tex_coord;

uniform mat4x4 model;
uniform mat4x4 view;
uniform mat4x4 projection;

uniform float size = 1.0;

// texture coordinates
const vec2 texc[4] = vec2[] (vec2(0, 0),
                             vec2(0, 1),
                             vec2(1, 0),
                             vec2(1, 1));

void main() {
    // vertex offsets from the center point
    float asize = size / 2;
    vec4 offset[4] = vec4[] (vec4(-asize, 0.0, -asize, 0.0),
                             vec4(-asize, 0.0,  asize, 0.0),
                             vec4( asize, 0.0, -asize, 0.0),
                             vec4( asize, 0.0,  asize, 0.0));
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {

            // vector coordinates
            vec4 vertexpos = (gl_in[i].gl_Position + offset[j]);
            vec4 position = projection * view * model * vertexpos;
            gl_Position = position;

            tex_coord = texc[j];
            EmitVertex();
        }
        EndPrimitive();
    }
}
```

Obviously the output is just a plane:

[image]

How must the code be changed to draw the plane as a billboard? I know I have to calculate the vertex coordinates (in the inner loop) utilizing the view matrix, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `offset` *after* you project `gl_in[i].gl_Position`:

```
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); ++i) 
{
    vec4 centerpt = projection * view * model * gl_in[i].gl_Position;
    for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j) 
    {
        gl_Position = centerpt + offset[j];
        tex_coord = texc[j];
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you for the answer. One remark though, `projection` still has to be applied in the inner loop, as the sprite would be stretched otherwise.

Comment: Can you also explain how an implementation would look like where only one axis is camera aligned? Say e.g. the sprite only "rotates" along the y axis.

Comment: @AdamS: No idea, sorry.